# Submitting HTML5 forms to email (via php?)

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I'm attempting to create an HTML5 form that submits basic vendor information without opening the user's email client, and with a "Submitted" (or something of the like) confirmation message as the form submits.  From my research, I've found that I'd need to use PHP for this, but I'm clueless as to how to implement the PHP scripts.

Here's my form:

```
<form id="vendorInfo" action="process_form_vendor.php" method="post">
    <label for="vendorName">Vendor Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="vendorName" name="vendorName" type="text" maxlength="30" required>
    <br />
    <label for="contactName">Contact Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="contactName" name="contactName" type="text" maxlength="35" required>
    <br />
    <label for="vendorType">Organization Type:</label>
    <br />
    <select id="vendorType" name="vendorType">
        <option value="carrier">
                Insurance Carrier
        </option>
        <option value="tech_crm">
                Technology/CRM Management
        </option>
        <option value="leadProvider">
                Lead Provider   
        </option>
        <option value="info_comm">
                Information/Communication
        </option>
        <option value="other">
                Other (please describe below)
        </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label for="other1">Other Organization Type:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="other1" name="other1" type="text" maxlength="25">
    <br />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <br />
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" maxlength="30" required>
    <br />
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>   
    <br />  
    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="tel" maxlength="12" required placeholder="xxx-xxx-xxxx">
    <br />
    <label for="questions">Any questions or comments? Leave them here:</label>
    <br />
    <textarea id="questions" name="questions" rows="10" maxlength="300"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
<fieldset id="selectionBox">
    <legend id="packageSelect">
    The following sponsorship packages are available for the Sales Summit; contact <a href="example@domain.com">Amanda</a> for pricing and                              details: 
    </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="packageSelect" value="Bronze Package" checked>&nbsp;Bronze
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="packageSelect" value="Silver Package">&nbsp;Silver
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="packageSelect" value="Gold Lunch Package">&nbsp;Gold&nbsp;(breakfast; exclusive sponsorship)
        <br />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="packageSelect" value="Gold Breakfast Package">&nbsp;Gold&nbsp;(lunch; exclusive sponsorship)
    <br />
    <br />
        <input type="radio" name="packageSelect" value="Gold Trade Show Package">&nbsp;Gold&nbsp;(trade&nbsp;show; exclusive sponsorship)
</fieldset>
<br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>&nbsp;<button type="reset">Reset</button><br />
```

And here is the PHP script I've written:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

$vendorName = $_POST['vendorName'];
$contactName = $_POST['contactName'];
$vendorType = $_POST['vendorType'];
$other1 = $_POST['other1'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$questions = $_POST['questions'];
$packageSelect = $_POST['packageSelect'];

if (empty($vendorName)||(empty($contactName)||(empty($vendorType)||(empty($email)||(empty($phone)||(empty($packageSelect)) {
    echo "Vendor Name, Contact Name, Vendor Type, Email, Phone, and Package Selection are mandatory!";
    exit;   
}

$email_from = 'example@domain.com';
$email_subject = '2014 SMS Sales Summit - New Vendor Reservation Request';
$email_body = "You have received a new vendor reservation request for the 2014 SMS Sales Summit from $contactName at $vendorName.\n".
              "Vendor Type: $vendorType\n".
              "Other Vendor Type: $other1\n".
              "Email Address: $email\n".
              "Phone Number: $phone\n".
              "Additional Questions: $questions\n".
              "Sponsorship Level: $packageSelect\n".

$to = 'example@domain.com';
$headers = "$email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header('Location: thank-you.html');



?>
```

I'm pretty sure that I've got everything set up correctly to pull the information submitted into the 'input' fields, but I'm not sure if I've implemented this correctly for the radio buttons and the drop down selector.  Any help with this implementation would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would follow this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Comment: and your php is ..? @Kerry Never use w3schools for anything - dangerously bad information

Comment: In your `<form>` tag add `<form id="vendorInfo" action="process_form.php" method="POST">`. Turn `<textarea id="vendorName">` into `<textarea id="vendorName" name="vendorName">`. Now create a file called `process_form.php` in the same directory that your form file exists. In `process_form.php` write this code `<?php echo $_POST['vendorName']; ?>`. Make sure to give your textareas, inputs, selects, etc meaningful `name=""` attributes so that your PHP can see them with `$_POST['someName']`

Comment: There are far too many resources out there for you to be stuck at this point: (1) http://webcheatsheet.com/php/form_processing.php (2) http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-processing.html (3) http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php

Comment: Thanks for the links @MonkeyZeus - I'll take a look at these and see if I can get this sorted.  This is literally the first time I've ever dabbled with PHP, so I apologize for the rudimentary question.

Comment: No problem, a lot of other users are much more viscous compared to what I commented so hopefully you can post another question with PHP code in the future. Try and follow my first comment closely because it should help you get started

Comment: @Dagon - I've updated with PHP code; not sure if I'm handling the radio buttons/dropdown selection correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add a method to your form as:

   `<form action="" method="post" id="vendorInfo">   //its an example`
2. Give name attribute to your all input filed as:

   `<input type="text" name="whatever">  //its an example`

then catch these by post method in php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['your_submit_name']))
{
$input_field=$_POST['your_input_field_name'];
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "your subject";
$message= "Hello mail!". "\r\n";
$message.= $input_field."\r\n";
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" ;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to submit the form to a mailer script on your server (mail.php). Once the server has the form information you can start building the message body there and use the php mail() function to send the message.

To learn about sending mail via php i suggest reading the php docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

You can also format the body of your message with html to have it render nicely in an email client.

You may have to research how to enable send mail via whatever server you'er using. I think by default it is disabled.