# How to post and store data

Tags: html, forms

I've coded a simple form using HTML5 and CSS3 with a submit button.

My questions are:

1. Where is sent the form-data when the form is submitted by a client?
2. What data gets sent to the server?
3. And finally, do I need the `<form>` **action** attribute in the HTML5 markup?

Comment: The form data gets sent to whatever you define in the action property. So <form method="POST" action="path/to/your/script.php">. The data that gets submitted is whatever you've put in the form..I don't mean to be rude, but these are really really basic questions and I suggest just reading through some w3schools HTML tutorials.

Comment: action is required to send the form data to another page. usually to php to validate and then decide to send it to the server or throw it away. You can view an example here. CTRL+U to view source. http://gc200314382.computerstudi.es/php/Lab3/

Comment: There is no `<action>` tag. There's an "action" attribute on the `<form>` tag that is used as the target URL for posting the form. The various `<input>` (etc) elements in the `<form>` body provide the parameters.

Comment: @Lynne. I did already read through the w3schools. My concern is more about the back end part. As Front End Dev I don't want to learn php. This is my first website. Is the form data handled by a server and if yes do I need the action tag?

Comment: @Pointy. Thank you for clearing my messy mind! So if I do add for example action="form.php" the server will handle that info for me to analyze or do I have to create a page named form.php?

Comment: Well *somebody* has to create the server code that responds to a form post. It's not magic.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21535078/6381711) should help you *(in case you opt to use PHP to handle your data)*.

Comment: @nyedidikeke. If possible I simply would like to not learn PHP at the moment. I'd rather let the server do it if it's possible. But thank you anyway. I saved the page you've sent as future reference if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
`<form>` has attribute `action` and here you can describe where your data will be send for example:

```
<form action="/something_action_on_your_server">
```

**2.**
Data which will be send is located in `name` attriubte of `<input>`, for example:

```
<form action="/something_action_on_your_server">
  <input name="first_name" >
</form>
```

and if you submit your form, something action get data like: `{name: 'something value from input'}`

**3.**`GET` is HTTP method, which is used to visit page or send something public information, if you want send something private information you have to use `POST` method instead `GET`

for example:

```
<form action="/something_action_on_your_server" method='get' >
```

**4.** You don't have to set `action` attribute, but if you will not do it, your form will be send to your current page :)

Comment: @Bartek Gladys. This is what I wanted to hear. My method is post and I will set the action attribute to desired value. Thank you!